# How can I add a property to a class through inheritance and then cast the base class to the new class?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm wondering if there is a way to do this inheritance situation in C#:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ItemExtended : Item
{
    public int ExtendedProp { get; set; }
}
```

And let's say I have a method that returns objects of type `Item`:

```
public Item[] GetItems();
```

How can I make code like this run?

```
ItemExtended[] itemsExt = GetItems().Cast(i => (ExtendedItem)i).ToArray();
```

Where the cast wouldn't fail, the Name property value would be preserved and I would have an additional property `ExtendedProp` that I could access?

**Edit** (hopefully to clear some confusion)

In this situation the `GetItems` method would only ever return items of type `Item`. I was wondering if there was a casting method that could convert a base type to an inherited type such that all base member values are conserved (without the use of cloning).

Answer (score 5):

If the runtime type of your object is `Item`, you can not cast it to an `ItemExtended` -- not unless there's a [user-defined conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288476(v=vs.71).aspx) that can create an `ItemExtended` from an `Item`. Note, however, that even then, you'll be creating a new instance of `ItemExtended`.

Inheritance in general doesn't work that way. In managed languages, downcasting only works if the runtime type of your object already is of the derived type. Instances of derived classes inherit all the data and behavior of their ancestor classes, but there's an ancestor doesn't have any knowledge of derived classes. Consider an example, where a derived class introduces a single new field. Firstly, the base class instance is *smaller in size*, so at the very least, a type cast would require allocating new memory. Second, you would have to decide between changing the runtime type of the original instance (which would be very weird indeed) or making a copy of the old data. The latter way would be very similar to the user-defined conversion scenario, except an user-defined conversion is explicitly invoked, and IMO better that way.

In unmanaged languages, you can of course make any arbitrary conversion you want -- but that just results in catastrophic failures if you do it wrong. In the example above, you would try to access the new field, but since it would not have been allocated for the instance, you would go beyond the boundaries of the object's memory space and access... whatever was in there, be it sensical or not.

If you want to introduce new behavior to existing classes, the C# way is via [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx). Extension properties aren't there yet, and may never be, so you don't get the property syntax. You may or may not be able to live with that.

You may also find it interesting, that in [XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295302.aspx), the concept of [attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011(v=vs.110).aspx) sort of fits what you are trying to do: you can define arbitrary new properties for whatever -- but if you look at the implementation, what you are really doing is creating a dictionary that maps objects to their associated property values, and the XAML compiler sugarcoats this by making the markup look like you've added the properties to those objects.

Comment: Can you tell me if this is a specific type of inheritance that .NET doesn't support and that another language does?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OfType` instead of `Cast`:

```
ItemExtended[] itemsExt = GetItems().OfType<ItemExtended>().ToArray();
```

Comment: Sorry, the question may not have been clear, the `GetItems` method would only return items of type `Item`. So I'm not trying to filter for items of type `ItemExtended` I want to convert and preserve the `Item` types.

Comment: In this case please refer to @Rytmis answer. He has explained why you can't do this.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with a few adjustments,

- use *Select()* instead of *Cast()* and
- *i as ItemExtended* rather than *(ItemExtended)i*

This line should cast it correctly:

> `ItemExtended[] itemsExt = GetItems().Select(i => i as ItemExtended).ToArray();`

Comment: I believe in this situation it would just return an array of null items since the conversion would fail.